# How to Restore and Back up Tables in apache pinot

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-pinot

I have some tables in my apache pinot server and i want to take the backup and restore data . I could not find any solution take the back up .
when we start to the other server Its difficult to retain the same info which was logged before.Pinot relies on deep-storage for storing backup copy of segments . It relies on Zookeeper to store metadata (table configs, schema, cluster state, etc).

Can someone suggest a solution for this ?